# Zeebus Puzzle #2

Tags: word, rebus, music

Below is a rebus puzzle for you to solve:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this

> [Tiptoe through the tulips?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eQQKVKjifQ), which (fun fact!) is an old song from 1929 which had some covers in the 1950s and 1960s as well! Apparently also it has made cameo appearances in [Harry Potter and the Philosopher's (Sorceror's) Stone, and in Wrecked, and in Insidious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiptoe_Through_the_Tulips)! Learn something new every day!

Comment: Always coming through with that research effort! All I have to do is read your updates to learn new things. :D

Comment: Haha thanks @davisj1691 !! -- if there's one thing I've really appreciated being on this website, it's all of the cool stuff that I learn while trying to solve the puzzles! :D